# Match and read file from zip

Tags: python, zip

I need to open an `manifest.v3` file and read the version field (xml file), and to do that I'm using the following code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
zf = ZipFile("somezip.zip")
for name in zf.namelist():
    if name.find("manifest.v3")  >= 0:
        for line in zf.read(name).split("\n"):
            for match in  re.findall(r'<value name="version">([0-9].*?)</value>',line):
                parts=match.split(".")
                localVersion=parts[1]
                print localVersion
zf.close()
```

The code above works good, but sometimes on the zipfile i have the `manifest.v3` file and `manifest.v3.old`, `manifest.v3.old.old` and so on.

How can I guarantee that I only get the result of the `manifest.v3` file? instead all others?

Comment: try by changing the condition `name.find("manifest.v3") >= 0` to `name == "manifest.v3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by changing the condition `name.find("manifest.v3") >= 0` to `name == "manifest.v3"`

Added a few examples below

```
In [181]: name = "manifest.v3"

In [182]: name.find("manifest.v3") >= 0
Out[182]: True

In [183]: name = "manifest.v3.old.old"

In [184]: name.find("manifest.v3") >= 0
Out[184]: True

In [185]: name == "manifest.v3"
Out[185]: False

In [186]: name = "manifest.v3"

In [187]: name == "manifest.v3"
Out[187]: True
```